# How to use a list<> method in C# VS

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding Lists in c# I have a method:

```
public void example(Employee emp)
```

Now I need to write

```
example();
```

in another method

But when I do it it shows me an error because I need to put something in () but I don't know what or how.
Thanks!

---

```
 public void SaveToFile(Employee emp)
        {
           

            var path2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "text.txt");

            File.AppendAllText(path2, emp2 + Environment.NewLine);
        }

//ABOVE ME IS THE METHOD I WANNA CALL
//BELOW IS THE START PROGRAM THING (employeedata is another script)

 private static void MainMenu(ref EmployeeData employeeData)
        {
    employeeData.SaveToFile(Employee emp);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Lists? Your method `example` needs an instance of `Employee` as parameter to work with. So when you call the method, you need to give it exactly that, for example `Employee John = new(); example(John);`

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes for now, the question is voted down because it doesn't really follow the rules of a 'good question' for stackoverflow (you can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ if you want to know why). Anyway, is my comment above, or the answer from @Antonio Skopin answering your question?

Comment: I have an employee called emp

Comment: and list called employee

Comment: and i cant write Example(employee emp) doesnt work

Comment: btw https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ it says web cant be reached :/

Comment: can you add the rest of your code, to your question please, where the complete `Example()` method as well as the list and your call of the method is included.

Comment: sure but its really REALLY long it has 3 scripts too so ill just put the main thing and also it says Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Comment: @FARIDFarid - I am downvoting because the question is not clear. Nothing in the code mentions lists as the title suggests. Also, what are you trying to do exactly? Please describe the ideal result, and any constraints/assumptions you have. Finally, post more code definitions to describe the objects in use, but not too much code (see minimal verifiable example in help).

Comment: I edited my question the part of script there it might be a little not so clean (lines start from not the right places) because I copy pasted it from notepad from VS

Comment: @FARIDFarid - where is the `List<>` ? Please add the definition for `Employee` and what data is in the text file.

Comment: private List<Employee> employees ;
         and like int i in arrays there is emp there

Comment: You can't upvote your own question. It is a bit hard to help with your question, because as @JAlex mentioned a few things are not quite clear and additionally the shared code has quite a few issues. It seems you first need to understand some programming basics, such as what is a class, an instance of a class, how to use methods (with arguments) and so on... This is more general stuff and needs quite a bit of explaining, stackoverflow is the wrong place for it (it is for specific programming issues). But fortunately there is a huge amount of tutorials out there.

Comment: I would also recommend to visit https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming, it is a very helpful community and more suited for broader questions (and they can refer you to specific tutorials and content with respect to your question)

Comment: i fixed my problem (sometimes I fix things not knowing how).

Comment: Divide your problem into small steps: 1. load a txt file into a string, 2. search and manipulate your string, 3. write a string to txt file. For each of these steps you find lots of good tutorials :)

Comment: ok ill try, I have a file.txt and I need to find a string called id which the person writes in, for example id = 213 and i need the thing to find a sentence that has 213 in it and delete it, I hope im clear XD

Comment: is there some sort of chat that we can talk in, it says we have a lot of comments please make it a chat but i dont know how, THANKS a lot your saving my butt here

Comment: There should be a button next to that message, to transfer to a chat

Comment: user19413065 has only 7 reputation, not yet enough to chat oof

Comment: So we can chat here. 
DO you know how to find what im struggling with?

Comment: Microsoft has one of the best documentations, with guides and examples. You already use the `File` class in your code above. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) are the docs of the class with all it's methods. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/search-strings) a guide on how to search strings. This should get you started.

Comment: @FARIDFarid - [edit] the question to add relevant information. **do not add code and info in the comments**.

Comment: Thanks ill check later just in case I'll explain again that I need to find a letter in the text file and delete sentence it is in.@roland

Answer (score 1):

After all the comments, I guess this is what you need: You must pass  one employee object in parameters when calling your void.

```
Employeee emp = new Employee();
emp.propertyOne = "stuff";
emp.propertyTwo = "more stuff";
example(emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a value between the () which are called parameters, because in your method you are asking for an object with the type of Employee. Please check the following url where you can learn more about parameters:

[Parameters in C#](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_method_parameters.php)

Comment: like i need to call the method in the main thing and for example : example(what exactly do i put here)  the () is a list<> list name is employee and i need emp to be the second thing but It shows errors and that i cant do that

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is a way to convert your `Employee` object into a `string` for writing into a file. Use the `.ToString()` override to do so.

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        // Constructor defaults
        ID = 0;
        Name = string.Empty;
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            // Check if ID and Name are set
            return ID > 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name);
        }
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // String representation of an Employee
        return $"{ID}, {Name}";
    }
}
```

Then you can have code that reads and writes to files

```
public static class EmployeeData 
{
    public static void AppendToFile(string filename, Employee employee)
    {
        // Use `ToString()` to convert `Employee` to `string`
        File.AppendAllText(filename, employee.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    public static Employee Parse(string description)
    {
        // Take a string of the form "100, John" and split it
        // into parts at the comma
        string[] parts = description.Trim().Split(',');
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        if (parts.Length > 0 && int.TryParse(parts[0].Trim(), out int id))
        {
            // If first part is an integer, assign it to the ID
            emp.ID = id;
        }
        if (parts.Length > 1)
        {
            // Assign second part to name
            emp.Name = parts[1];
        }
        return emp;
    }
    public static List<Employee> ReadFromFile(string filename)
    {
        // Read all text from file as separate lines
        List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            // Convert each line of text into an Employee object
            Employee emp = Parse(line);
            if (emp.IsValid)
            {
                // If the object is valid add to the list
                list.Add(emp);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

and the above is used in the following proof of concept code below:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Peter",
        };

        EmployeeData.AppendToFile("test.txt", emp1);

        Employee emp2 = new Employee()
        {
            ID  = 2,
            Name = "Maria",
        };

        EmployeeData.AppendToFile("test.txt", emp2);

        List<Employee> employees = EmployeeData.ReadFromFile("test.txt");

        foreach (var item in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            // This calls item.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

which prints the following on the console window the first time its run

```
1,  Peter
2,  Maria
```

Note that each time the program runs it adds to the above creating duplicates. That is a subject of a different question, on how to write an `.Equals()` function to check for duplicates.